# Using RazorEngine to create plain text templates

Tags: razor, razorengine

There are lots of issues with whitespaces(especially with line breaks) where razor expressions are mixed with plain text. It's quite difficult cope with them.

For example - the whole sentence will be unfortunately splitted by line break:

```
@if(something)
{
@This is some text
}
and this rest of this text
```

Another example - I used some custom helpers to conditionally render text. But when the condition is not met there is empty line rendered.

```
@Html.IfNotNull("Some text 1",@Model.prop1)
@Html.IfNotNull("Some text 2",@Model.prop2)  //false
@Html.IfNotNull("Some text 3",@Model.prop3)
```

Renders to:

```
Some text 1

Some text 3
```

But I need:

```
Some text 1
Some text 3
```

Any suggestions? Maybe there are template engines better for my case?

Answer (score 0):

Razor interprets your spaces literally so you can always just write them in the same line:

```
@if (true) { <text>This is some text</text> }and this rest of this text

@Html.IfNotNull("Some text 1",@Model.prop1) @Html.IfNotNull("Some text 2",@Model.prop2) @Html.IfNotNull("Some text 3",@Model.prop3)
```

Output:

```
This is some text and this rest of this text

Some text 1  Some text 3
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But templates have a lot of IFs, sometimes nested and this solution makes them much harder to read.

Comment: And chunks of text used in helpers are quite long which would produce very long lines

Comment: You should consider your approach then. Perhaps there is a better way for you to design the views?

Comment: From experience, I can tell you that whenever I start to notice a pattern where things get more and more complex, it usually means I need to take a step back and consider the way I am doing things. In this case, for instance, it looks to me like it's not the technology that is limiting you, it's how you are using it.